# Set permanent array element

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

Im creating an array where each element is pulled in from a database, so each time the app runs it fetches new data from the DB.

Is it possible to hardcode the first element of the array? So each time the app loads the first element will always be "My First Element"?

This is how I'm creating my dynamic array from Firebase, Firstly I create an array of drivers, I then filter the array to remove duplicated and end up with "sortedDriverName", But I wish to statically add an element to the start of that array each launch

```
let key = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "uid") as! String
        print(key);
        firebaseDB.collection("message").document(key).collection("messages").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            }
            else {
                self.driverArr.removeAll()
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
                    let msgdata = document.data() as! [String:Any]
                    print(msgdata)
                    var msgObj = Message()
                    if let name = msgdata["name"] as? String {
                        msgObj.name = name
                    }
                    self.driverArr.append(msgObj)

                }
                if self.driverArr.count < 1 {
                    print("No Drivers")
                }
                else{
                    print("*** Driver Names array ***")
                    //print(self.driverArr)
                    self.driverName = self.driverArr.compactMap({$0.name})
                    self.sortedDriverName = Array(Set(self.driverName))
                    print(self.sortedDriverName)
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate your dynamic array and then after you have finished just insert an item in the array at index 0.

```
sortedDriverName.insert("My first driver", at: 0)
```

Or

Initialize the array at the start with your first element and then append the rest of the rows

```
self.sortedDriverArray = ["My first driver"]

for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
    // append more elements
}
```